# Custom street view button/control

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to be able to have my own 'street view' button using google maps api v3. When the button is clicked I want this to load street view based on my latlng of the marker. Then I would like the button to change to say 'Back to map' and this would then load the default map view again.

I am trying to use getStreetView(myLatlng) when the button is clicked but it's not loading the street view so I must be missing something here but I can't seem to find any help for this on the web. Here's my code:-

```
        var map;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.333029,-83.04559);

    /**
     * The HomeControl adds a control to the map that simply
     * returns the user to Chicago. This constructor takes
     * the control DIV as an argument.
     * @constructor
     */
    function customStreetView(controlDiv, map) {

      // Offset from the corner
      controlDiv.style.padding = '10px';

      // Create control div
      var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
      controlUI.innerHTML = "View on street";
      controlUI.className = "google_map_button"
      controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

      // Setup the click event listener
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
        var panorama = map.getStreetView(myLatlng);
        if(panorama){panorama.setVisible(false);}
      });

    }

    function initialize() {

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 17,
            center: myLatlng,
            panControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: true,
            streetViewControl: false,
            overviewMapControl: true
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        // Set the marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            icon: 'images/google-map-marker.png'
        });

        // Create the DIV to hold the control and
        // call the HomeControl() constructor passing
        // in this DIV.
        var homeControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var homeControl = new customStreetView(homeControlDiv, map);

        homeControlDiv.index = 1;

        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(homeControlDiv);       

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    }

    </script>
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. of course you must set `visible` to `true` when you want to show the panorama
2. the `position` will not be set via an argument of `getStreetView()`, you must set the property via `set`, `setValues`, `setPosition` or `setOptions`

   ```
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
     map.getStreetView().setOptions({visible:true,position:myLatlng});
   });
   ```